# Converting a SoftwareBitmap or WriteableBitmap to cv::Mat in c++/cx

Tags: c++, opencv, c++-cx

I tried to convert a WriteableBitmap to a cv::Mat in a c++/cx Microsoft universial App. But when I try to progress with the created Mat, I get the following error:

[image]

This is my Code:

```
void App1::MainPage::processImage(SoftwareBitmap^ bitmap)
{
     WriteableBitmap^ wb = ref new WriteableBitmap(bitmap->PixelWidth, bitmap->PixelHeight);
     bitmap->CopyToBuffer(wb->PixelBuffer);
     Mat img_image(wb->PixelHeight, wb->PixelWidth, CV_8UC3,(void*)wb->PixelBuffer);
     //next step results in error
     cvtColor(img_image, img_image, CV_BGR2BGRA);
     ...
}
```

So my final question:
How to convert the SoftwareBitmap or the WriteableBitmap to a cv::Mat?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that [`PixelBuffer` is not a `void *`, it is an `IBuffer^`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.pixelbuffer.aspx).

To get at the raw data, you can either use the [`IBufferByteAccess` interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/Hh846267(v=vs.85).aspx) if you're comfortable with COM programming, or you can initialize a [`DataReader` with an `IBuffer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.datareader.frombuffer.aspx) if you'd prefer to stay in WinRT (although this technique will make a copy of the data).

Answer (score 0):

I used the DataReader to solve the problem:

```
void App1::MainPage::processImage(SoftwareBitmap^ bitmap)
{
     WriteableBitmap^ wb = ref new WriteableBitmap(bitmap->PixelWidth, bitmap->PixelHeight);
     bitmap->CopyToBuffer(wb->PixelBuffer);
     IBuffer^ buffer = wb->PixelBuffer;
     auto reader = ::Windows::Storage::Streams::DataReader::FromBuffer(buffer);
     BYTE *extracted = new BYTE[buffer->Length];
     reader->ReadBytes(Platform::ArrayReference<BYTE>(extracted, buffer->Length));
     Mat img_image(wb->PixelHeight, wb->PixelWidth, CV_8UC4, extracted);
     cvtColor(img_image, img_image, CV_RGBA2BGRA);
     ...
}
```

Thx to Peter Torr for the hint.