# How do you convert a C# WritableBitmap to a EmguCV/OpenCV Mat?

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv, mat, writeablebitmap

I have a WritableBitmap, and I would like to convert it to a EmguCV/OpenCV Mat. How would I go about doing that? I've tried several chain solutions (WritableBitmap -> Bitmap -> Map) from code online, but I haven't found anything that works. Thanks!

Comment: You see  [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37383502/2050745)  and trying?

Comment: @NejcGalof Yes, I saw that answer. However, it's for C++ and not C#, so it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find this works pretty well:

```
    public static Mat ToMat(BitmapSource source)
    {
        if (source.Format == PixelFormats.Bgra32)
        {
            Mat result = new Mat();
            result.Create(source.PixelHeight, source.PixelWidth, DepthType.Cv8U, 4);
            source.CopyPixels(Int32Rect.Empty, result.DataPointer, result.Step * result.Rows, result.Step);
            return result;
        }
        else if (source.Format == PixelFormats.Bgr24)
        {
            Mat result = new Mat();
            result.Create(source.PixelHeight, source.PixelWidth, DepthType.Cv8U, 3);
            source.CopyPixels(Int32Rect.Empty, result.DataPointer, result.Step * result.Rows, result.Step);
            return result;
        }
        else if (source.Format == PixelFormats.Pbgra32)
        {
            Mat result = new Mat();
            result.Create(source.PixelHeight, source.PixelWidth, DepthType.Cv8U, 4);
            source.CopyPixels(Int32Rect.Empty, result.DataPointer, result.Step * result.Rows, result.Step);
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception(String.Format("Conversion from BitmapSource of format {0} is not supported.", source.Format));
        }
    }
```

Doug