# How to convert an SoftwareBitmap Image to cv::Mat Image?

Tags: xaml, uwp-xaml, xamlwriter

I am referencing this link -> [Converting a SoftwareBitmap or WriteableBitmap to cv::Mat in c++/cx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37375414/converting-a-softwarebitmap-or-writeablebitmap-to-cvmat-in-c-cx)

But every time I try to put this into the code it shows me this error...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPABr.png)

You can see the background highlighted part.. where I have used this conversion part in the code....

and this is the reference link for code
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/CameraGetPreviewFrame/cpp/MainPage.xaml.cpp

Comment: Does your project can not be builded? Please try to comment out your  convert SoftwareBitmap Image to cv::Mat Image, can it be builded?

Comment: I am able to get pass that "app didn't start error" but the conversion of SoftwareBitmap to cv::Mat is not working. The cv::Mat is working when image is read from Assets folder...